# How to disable multi user calendar view

Tags: calendar

We have one requirement where we need to disable multi user calendar view for certain users.

Based on my search I found that there is no option to disable it, if it is not possible then is any other way to achieve this requirement.

I am also looking for option to disable "All Users" standard list view of multi user calendar which may solve our problem, as of now I didn't see any way to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable multi calendar. But you may get your desired result by adjusting sharing settings for the Calendar object. In Admin Setup go to Security Controls -> Sharing Settings

Under Sharing settings, Choose the Calender Object.

You can assign the following access levels to personal calendars.

1. Hide Details - Others can see whether the user is available at given times, but can not see any other information about the nature of events in the user’s calendar.
2. Hide Details and Add Events  - In addition to the sharing levels set by Hide Details, users can insert events in other users’ calendars.
3. Show Details - Users can see detailed information about events in other users’ calendars.
4. Show Details and Add Events - In addition to the sharing levels set by Show Details, users can insert events in other users’ calendars.
5. Full Access - Users can see detailed information about events in other users’ calendars, insert events in other users’ calendars, and edit existing events in other users’ calendars.